# angular jsonp return status code 0 instead of 401

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app that makes a call to a rest endpoint which is secure and returns 401 when accessed. I have defined an interceptor in my app so that errors are caught and upon 401 the app should redirect to a login page. That all sounds very straightforward but when I run this in a browser I get status code 0 in my error response. However in my Chrome console I can see a log which says the requested url resulted in a 401.

I need to add that JS files are being hosted on localhost:9000 and the app that gives the 401 response is on localhost:8080. What is wrong?

```
    angular.module('ndbAdminUIApp', ['ngResource']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'views/main.html',
            controller : 'MainCtrl'
        }).when('/login', {
            templateUrl : 'views/login.html',
            controller : 'LoginCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/'
        });

        var interceptor = ['$location', '$q', function ($location, $q) {
            function success(response) {
                return response;
              }

            function error(response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                  $location.path('#login');
                  return $q.reject(response);
                }
                else {
                  return $q.reject(response);
                }
              }

            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(success, error);
              };
          }];

      $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
    }])


    angular.module('ndbAdminUIApp').factory('ndbSystemService', function($http) {
        return {
            heartBeat: function() {
                $http.jsonp('http://localhost\:8080/ndb-service/r/system/hb?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
              },
          };
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out Angular cannot really figure out the response code while using JSONP and it is not Angular's fault because all it gets is a function call. Therefore for people doing this the only option is to put the web pages and rest services on the same host.

Comment: Actually, I wrote an enterprise app using django and angular on separate domains, and using the http-auth-interceptor for login checking. It works perfectly. So it definitely can be done.

Comment: This is interesting but to be clear, are you doing jsonp? If you are doing post, get and things like that there will be no problem and this all works fine. The problem is when you make calls with jsonp.

Comment: @Farzad Could you elaborate on the mechanism that make this impossible ? I never explicitly used any JSONP in my code so why is this in the mix ? In fact, I just looked up what JSONP is.

Comment: @StephaneEybert You need to use jsonp if you are going to consume data from a different domain than the one that hosts the application. As to why this didn't work with Angular, the details are very rusty for me right now. It might have been an angular issue that is fixed now.

Comment: @Farzad I have the same problem. My web pages are hosted on a different host than the API. I don't use JSONP. Rather, I have enabled CORS on the web server but I still get a zero status though in Fiddler it is obvious that a 401 is being returned.

Answer (score 0):

your server response should be something like angular.callbacks._0({jsonResponseData}) . In your server code, instead of sending jsonResponseData, you would create a response(basically concatenation of strings) as a response. Server code would be roughly like this:

```
var stringForResponse = new StringBuilder();
                stringForResponse.Append(callbackFunctionName);
                stringForResponse.Append("(");
                stringForResponse.Append(jsonResponseData);
                stringForResponse.Append(")");
                toString = stringForResponse.ToString();
```